# Flask-Admin sort on one to many counted field

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

Let's assume we have a one to many relation between Owner and Screens (a owner can own multiple screens).

It is possible to display a column showing the number of screens owned by each owner by using an hybrid_property and calling count() on the relationship.
However I have not find a way to make this value computed value sortable in the web interface : 
If I add number_of_screens in column_sortable_list, I got the following error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 71, in <module>
    admin.add_view(OwnerAdmin(Owner, db.session))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\contrib\sqla\view.py", line 319, in __init__
    menu_icon_value=menu_icon_value)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\model\base.py", line 718, in __init__
    self._refresh_cache()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\model\base.py", line 795, in _refresh_cache
    self._sortable_columns = self.get_sortable_columns()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\contrib\sqla\view.py", line 539, in get_sortable_columns
    column, path = self._get_field_with_path(c)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask_admin\contrib\sqla\view.py", line 365, in _get_field_with_path
    value = getattr(model, attribute)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\ext\hybrid.py", line 740, in __get__
    return self.expr(owner)
  File "app.py", line 48, in number_of_screens
    return self.screens.count()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\orm\attributes.py", line 193, in __getattr__
    key)
AttributeError: Neither 'InstrumentedAttribute' object nor 'Comparator' object associated with Owner.screens has an attribute 'count'
```

Here is a sample code to illustrate the issue :

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

import flask_admin as admin
from flask_admin.contrib import sqla
from flask_admin.contrib.sqla.filters import IntGreaterFilter

# Create application
app = Flask(__name__)

# Create dummy secrey key so we can use sessions
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = '123456790'

# Create in-memory database
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///sample_db_2.sqlite'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_ECHO'] = True
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


# Flask views
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return '<a href="/admin/">Click me to get to Admin!</a>'


class Screen(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'screen'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    width = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    height = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    owner_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('owner.id'))
    owner = db.relationship('Owner',
        backref=db.backref('screens', lazy='dynamic'))

    @hybrid_property
    def number_of_pixels(self):
        return self.width * self.height


class Owner(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'owner'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode)

    @hybrid_property
    def number_of_screens(self):
        return self.screens.count()


class ScreenAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    ''' Flask-admin can not automatically find a hybrid_property yet. You will
        need to manually define the column in list_view/filters/sorting/etc.'''
    list_columns = ['id', 'width', 'height', 'number_of_pixels']
    column_sortable_list = ['id', 'width', 'height', 'number_of_pixels']

    # make sure the type of your filter matches your hybrid_property
    column_filters = [IntGreaterFilter(Screen.number_of_pixels,
                                       'Number of Pixels')]

class OwnerAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    ''' Flask-admin can not automatically find a hybrid_property yet. You will
        need to manually define the column in list_view/filters/sorting/etc.'''
    list_columns = ['id', 'name', 'number_of_screens']
    column_sortable_list = ['id', 'name', 'number_of_screens']


# Create admin
admin = admin.Admin(app, name='Example: SQLAlchemy2', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(ScreenAdmin(Screen, db.session))
admin.add_view(OwnerAdmin(Owner, db.session))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # Create DB
    db.create_all()

    # Start app
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to add a [hybrid property expression](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html#defining-expression-behavior-distinct-from-attribute-behavior) modifier for your `number_of_screens` hybrid property. This is a method that emits the SQL required to calculate the screen count for a particular owner. e.g.

```
class Owner(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'owner'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Unicode)

    @hybrid_property
    def number_of_screens(self):
        return len(self.screens)

    @number_of_screens.expression
    def number_of_screens(cls):
        return db.select([db.func.count(Screen.id)]).where(Screen.owner_id == cls.id).label("number_of_screens")
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for !

Comment: `TypeError: count() takes exactly one argument (0 given)` :(

Comment: Got it to work with `return len(self.screens)` under the `@hybrid_property`.